# Impersonate User while installing Certificate

Tags: c#

Have a problem to impersonate an admin User to Install .cer (Certificate Files) File into LocalComputer...Installing for CurrentUser work perfekt.

I always get error message "Acces Denied".

Using following Code for Impersonation:

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Security.Principal;

public class ImpersonatedUser : IDisposable
{

    IntPtr userHandle;

    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;



    public ImpersonatedUser(string domain,string user, string password)
    {

        userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool loggedOn = LogonUser(

            user,

            domain,

            password,

            LogonType.Interactive,

            LogonProvider.Default,

            out userHandle);



        if (!loggedOn)

            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());



        // Begin impersonating the user

        impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);



    }



    public void Dispose()
    {

        if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            CloseHandle(userHandle);

            userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            impersonationContext.Undo();

        }

    }



    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    static extern bool LogonUser(

        string lpszUsername,

        string lpszDomain,

        string lpszPassword,

        LogonType dwLogonType,

        LogonProvider dwLogonProvider,

        out IntPtr phToken

        );



    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);



    enum LogonType : int
    {

        Interactive = 2,

        Network = 3,

        Batch = 4,

        Service = 5,

        NetworkCleartext = 8,

        NewCredentials = 9,

    }



    enum LogonProvider : int
    {

        Default = 0,
        WINNT50 = 3,

    }
```

This is Certificate Install Method:

```
private static void InstallCertificate(string cerFileName, StoreName storeName)
        {
            LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFileName);
            X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            try
            {

                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                    store.Add(certificate);
                    store.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string CertName = Path.GetFileName(cerFileName);
                string source = e.Source.ToString();
                string message = e.Message.ToString();
                string messagetext = string.Format("Certificate installation \"{0}\" was not succsessfull Error: {1}", CertName, message);
                StringBuilder messagestring = new StringBuilder();
                messagestring.Append(source);
                messagestring.Append(message);
                MessageBox.Show(messagetext, "Install Certificate Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

And this is how i call the Method within ImpersonatedUser.

```
using (new ImpersonatedUser(loginInfo.DomainName, loginInfo.UserName, loginInfo.Password))
                            {


                                MessageBox.Show(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                                InstallCertificate(certpath, StoreName.TrustedPublisher);

                }
```

Comment: I bet on a User Access List issue, and privilege elevation...

Answer (score 0):

MS has a good help page located and example at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

The clear difference between your code is you do not include the `[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]` qualifier on your function.  If this is part of a library you will need to do so for the entire library too.

*I'm assuming the user you are logging in as has rights to install the certificate -- please make sure your user has these rights.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that I use for impersonation of service accounts and it's proven to work well:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ImpersonationUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Facilitates impersonation of a Windows User.
    /// </summary>
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public class Impersonation : IDisposable
    {
        public string Environment { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public enum LogonType
        {
            Interactive = 2,
            Network = 3,
            Batch = 4,
            Service = 5,
            Unlock = 7,
            NetworkClearText = 8,
            NewCredentials = 9
        }

        public enum LogonProvider
        {
            Default = 0,
            WinNT35 = 1,
            WinNT40 = 2,
            WinNT50 = 3
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Windows Token.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;

        /// <summary>
        /// The impersonated User.
        /// </summary>
        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;

        public Impersonation()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Impersonation class. Provides domain, user name, and password for impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="domainName">Domain name of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">Name of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Uses the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
        /// the specified user, domain, and password.
        /// </remarks>
        public Impersonation(AccountCredentials credentials)
        {            
            string[] splitName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
            string name = (splitName.Length > 0) ? splitName[0] : null;

            LogonType logonType = LogonType.Interactive;
            LogonProvider logonProvider = LogonProvider.Default;

            if (name != credentials.Domain)
            {
                logonType = LogonType.NewCredentials;
                logonProvider = LogonProvider.WinNT50;
            }

            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(
                                credentials.UserName,
                                credentials.Domain,
                                credentials.Password,
                                (int)logonType,
                                (int)logonProvider,
                                out this._handle);

            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                // Something went wrong.
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }

            this.impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());    
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Impersonation class. Provide domain, user name, and password for impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="domainName">Domain name of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">Name of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password of the impersonated user.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Uses the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
        /// the specified user, domain, and password.
        /// </remarks>
        public Impersonation(string domainName, string userName, string password)
        {
            string[] splitName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
            string name = (splitName.Length > 0) ? splitName[0] : null;

            LogonType logonType = LogonType.Interactive;
            LogonProvider logonProvider = LogonProvider.Default;

            if (name != domainName)
            {
                logonType = LogonType.NewCredentials;
                logonProvider = LogonProvider.WinNT50;
            }

            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(
                                userName,
                                domainName,
                                password,
                                (int)logonType,
                                (int)logonProvider,
                                out this._handle);

            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                // Something went wrong.
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }

            this.impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool LogonUser(
                string lpszUsername,
                string lpszDomain,
                string lpszPassword,
                int dwLogonType,
                int dwLogonProvider,
                out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.impersonatedUser.Dispose();
            this._handle.Dispose();
        }

        private static string[] GetAccountInfo(string accountInfo)
        {
            return accountInfo.Split(' ');
        }
    }

    public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true) { }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

AccountCredentials.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;

namespace ImpersonationUtil
{
    public class AccountCredentials
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }

        public AccountCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            Password = password;
            Domain = domain;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
AccountCredentials credentials = new AccountCredentials("user", "password", "domain");
using (new Impersonation(credentials))
{
    // do work under the impersonated user
}
```

The important thing to note is that you must be using the correct logon type and logon provider when trying to impersonate an account not on the same domain as the active domain. I check for this and automatically assign the correct logon type and logon provider in the Impersonation constructor.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer..I implemented your class but still get Access denied.

Comment: The strange thing is that if i do AccountCredentials credentials = new AccountCredentials(loginInfo.UserName, loginInfo.Password, loginInfo.DomainName);
                            using (new Impersonation(credentials))
                            {
                                // do work under the impersonated user
                                MessageBox.Show(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups.ToString());
                                                            InstallCertificate(certpath, StoreName.TrustedPublisher);
                            }